# Dialog box isn't created when button is clicked

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

When a button with id "income_btn" is clicked, a dialog box is to be created.
The problem is that when I click the button nothing happens.

Here's the code:

button:

```
private void addData () {

    //Fab Button Income
    fab_income_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            incomeDataInsert();
        }
    });
}
```

Insertion:

```
public void incomeDataInsert(){
    final AlertDialog.Builder myDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    View myView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout_for_insert_data,null);
    myDialog.setView(myView);
    
    final AlertDialog dialog=myDialog.create();
    System.out.println("Dialog created");

     final EditText edtAmount=myView.findViewById(R.id.amount_edt);
     final EditText edtType= myView.findViewById(R.id.type_edt);
     final EditText edtNote=myView.findViewById(R.id.note_edt);

    Button btnSave1= myView.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    Button btnCancel1= myView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);


    btnSave1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String type = edtType.getText().toString().trim();
            String amount = edtAmount.getText().toString().trim();
            String note = edtNote.getText().toString().trim();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(type)) {
                edtType.setError("Required Field");
                return;
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(amount)) {
                edtAmount.setError("Required Field");
                return;
            }
            int ouramountint = Integer.parseInt(amount);

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(note)) {
                edtNote.setError("Required Field");
                return;

            }
            //myDialog.dismiss();
        }

    });
    //myDialog.show();


    btnCancel1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();

}
```

What I want to achieve is, when I click fab_income_btn, incomeDataInsert() should be called and it should create a dialog where I can enter some values into input fields (defined in custom_layout_insert_data.xml).